# Save Javascript toggle state with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I would like to save the state of site-header display. How i can save it with Jquery Cookie?

```
(function ($) {
// The initial load event will try and pull the cookie to see if the toggle is "open"
var openToggle = getCookie("show") || false;
if ( openToggle )
    div.style.display = "block";
else
    div.style.display = "none";
if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){
    // Index (home) page
    div.style.display = "block";
}
// The click handler will decide whether the toggle should "show"/"hide" and set the cookie.
$('#Togglesite-header').click(function() {
    var closed = $("site-header").is(":hidden");
    if ( closed )
       div.style.display = "block";
    else
        div.style.display = "none";
    setCookie("show", !closed, 365 );
});

});
```

Comment: *How* is the code not working? What are those `set`/`getCookie` functions? Can you share their implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. Firstly you're defining an IIFE-like function wrapper, but you never invoke it, so your code won't run. You need to add `(jQuery)` to the end to pass in a reference, or use an actual `document.ready` event handler if that's your intention.

Secondly, cookies only store strings, so you need to either convert the string to a boolean (which is a little bit of a minefield with JS's data typing), or alternatively you can just compare strings. Try this:

```js
(function($) {
  var $div = $(div);
  
  var openToggle = getCookie("show") == 'true';
  $div.toggle(openToggle);
    
  if (window.location.pathname == '/')
    $div.show();
  
  $('#Togglesite-header').click(function() {
    var closed = $("site-header").is(":hidden");
    $div.toggle(closed);
    setCookie("show", !closed, 365);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Two further things to note. Firstly I amended this to use jQuery. If you've already loaded it, you may as well make use of its simplicity to make your code less verbose.

Secondly, it assumes your `getCookie()` and `setCookie()` functions are working; you've not shown their implementation, but as there's *lots* of working examples of those I don't believe this to be your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but i got error that i can't undestand since i beginner at jquery.

 `'Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined'`

Comment: That means you've not included the cookie library you're using in the page properly

Comment: I use js-cookie: github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie And load it with wp_enqueue_script, is it wrong?

Comment: For some reason that script is not being included. Unfortunately I've never used Wordpress so can't offer any advice. I'd suggest starting a new question or searching if you're still having issues.